# What is wrong with my string generating program?

Tags: c, string, memory, concurrency, buffer

I have a program that takes 7 arguments. For now the first argument is ignored. My main function fcfsa takes 8 arguments : s1, s2, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2. s1 and s2 are the char pointer variables and x1..z2 are the last 6 integer arguments in argv in consecutive order.

fcfsa should do this: 
The first string, s1, will consist of a x1 R's, followed by y1 w's, followed by z1 R's.
The second string, s2, will consist of x1 r's, followed by x2 R's, followed by y2 w's, followed by z2 R's.

But I am not getting the correct output when executing the program with ./main 0 4 2 7 3 6 5 
Again the first argument 0 is ignored for now.

This is my output:

```
inputs: 0 4 2 7 3 6 5 
maxSize=27

Part 1

RRRRwwRRRRRRRRRRRR+Y?
rrrrRRRwwwwww

0 4 2.0 0.86364
```

And my main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pslibrary.h"

void part0(char *s1, char *s2);
void display(char *heading, char *s1, char *s2);
void fcfsa(char *s1, char *s2, int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    printf("Assignment 0 program was written by Marcus Lorenzana\n");
    if (argc != 8) {
        printf("Error. Wrong number of arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("inputs: ");
    for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%s ",argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    //Get maximum string size
    int maxSize=0;
    for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        maxSize+=atoi(argv[i]);
    }
    printf("maxSize=%d\n",maxSize);

    char str1[maxSize],str2[maxSize];

    fcfsa(str1,str2,atoi(argv[2]),atoi(argv[3]),atoi(argv[4]),atoi(argv[5]),atoi(argv[6]),atoi(argv[7]));
   display("Part 1\n",str1,str2);

        return 0;
}
```

And my program containing fcfsa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pslibrary.h"

void part0(char *s1, char *s2){
    strcpy(s1,"RRwwwwwRRRRRRRRR"); 
    strcpy(s2,"rrRRRRwwwwwwwwrrRRRRRRR"); 
}

void display(char *heading, char *s1, char *s2){
    printf("\n"); 
    printf("%s\n",heading); 
    printf("%s\n",s1); 
    printf("%s\n",s2); 
    printf("\n"); 
    int s1len = strlen(s1); 
    int s2len = strlen(s2); 
    int i,s1cnt,s2cnt,s1cnt2,s2cnt2;
    s1cnt=s2cnt=0;  
    s1cnt2=s2cnt2=0;
    for (i = 0; i < s1len; i++) {
        if (s1[i]=='r')
            s1cnt++; 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < s2len; i++) {
        if (s2[i]=='r')
            s2cnt++; 
    }
    float average_r = (s1cnt+s2cnt)/2; 

    for (i = 0; i < s1len; i++) {
        if (s1[i]=='R')
            s1cnt2++; 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < s2len; i++) {
        if (s2[i]=='R')
            s2cnt2++; 
    }

    int longest; 
    if (s2len > s1len) {
        longest = s2len; 
    } else {
        longest = s1len; 
    }

    float average_R = (float)(s1cnt2+s2cnt2)/longest;

    printf("%d %d %.1f %.5f\n",s1cnt,s2cnt,average_r,average_R); 
}

void fcfsa(char *s1, char *s2, int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2){
    //s1: x1 R's, y1 w's, 0 or more r's, z1 R's
    //s2: x1 r's, x2 R's, y2 w's, 0 or more r's, z2 R's 
    int i;
        //s1 fill
    int s1_start=0;
        int s1_end=x1;  
    for (i = s1_start; i < s1_end; i++) {
        s1[i]='R';
    } 
    s1_start=s1_end; 
    s1_end+=y1; 
    for (i = s1_start; i < s1_end; i++) {
        s1[i]='w';
    }
    s1_start=s1_end;
    s1_end+=z1;
    for (i = s1_start; i < s1_end; i++){
        s1[i]='R'; 
    }
    s1[s1_end]='\0';
        //printf("s1:%s\n",s1);     
    //s2 fill
    int s2_start=0;
    int s2_end=x1;
    for (i = s2_start; i < s2_end; i++) {
        s2[i]='r';
    }
    s2_start=s2_end; 
    s2_end+=x2;
    for (i = s2_start; i < s2_end; i++) {
        s2[i]='R';
    }
    s2_start=s2_end;
    s2_end+=y2;
    for (i = s2_start; i < s2_end; i++) {
        s2[i]='w';
    }
    s2_start=s2_end;
    s2_end+=z2; 
    for (i = s2_start; i < s2_end; i++) {
        s1[i]='R';
    }
    s2[s2_end]='\0';
    //printf("s2:%s\n",s2); 
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: You might like to try to debug this yourself. Read here on how to do this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You have `s1` in `fcfsa` when you want to append the second batch of `R`s. It might be a good idea to have just one function that you call twice, namely once for each string (with the number of `r`s zero for `s1`);

Comment: Thanks that would prob be a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code:

```
s2_start=s2_end;
s2_end+=z2; 
for (i = s2_start; i < s2_end; i++) {
    s1[i]='R';
 // ^^^^^^^  error
}
s2[s2_end]='\0';
```

That line should be:

```
    s2[i]='R';
```

You can change your coding habits to avoid making mistakes like this. As an example, divide `fcfsa` into two functions.

```
void fcfsa(char *s1, char *s2, int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2){
   fcfsa1(s1, x1, y1, z1);
   fcfsa2(s2, x1, x2, y2, z2);
}
```

where

```
void fcfsa1(char *s, int x1, int y1, int z1){
   //s: x1 R's, y1 w's, 0 or more r's, z1 R's
   int i;
   int start=0;
   int end=x1;  
   for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
      s[i]='R';
   } 

   start=end; 
   end+=y1; 
   for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
      s[i]='w';
   }
   start=end;
   end+=z1;
   for (i = start; i < end; i++){
      s[i]='R'; 
   }
   s[end]='\0';
}

void fcfsa2(char *s, int x1, int x2, int y2, int z2){
    //s: x1 r's, x2 R's, y2 w's, 0 or more r's, z2 R's 
    int i;
    int start=0;
    int end=x1;
    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        s[i]='r';
    }
    start=end; 
    end+=x2;
    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        s[i]='R';
    }
    start=end;
    end+=y2;
    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        s[i]='w';
    }
    start=end;
    end+=z2; 
    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        s[i]='R';
    }
    s[end]='\0';
}
```

You can further simplify the code by writing a helper function to fill the array with characters.

```
void fill(char *s, int start, int end, char c)
{
   int i;
   for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
      s[i]=c;
   } 
}
```

Then, `fcfsa1` and `fcfsa2` can be simplified to:

```
void fcfsa1(char *s, int x1, int y1, int z1){
   //s: x1 R's, y1 w's, 0 or more r's, z1 R's
   int start=0;
   int end=x1;  
   fill(s, start, end, 'R');

   start=end; 
   end+=y1; 
   fill(s, start, end, 'w');

   start=end;
   end+=z1;
   fill(s, start, end, 'R');

   s[end]='\0';
}

void fcfsa2(char *s, int x1, int x2, int y2, int z2){
    //s: x1 r's, x2 R's, y2 w's, 0 or more r's, z2 R's 
    int start=0;
    int end=x1;
    fill(s, start, end, 'r');

    start=end; 
    end+=x2;
    fill(s, start, end, 'R');

    start=end;
    end+=y2;
    fill(s, start, end, 'w');

    start=end;
    end+=z2; 
    fill(s, start, end, 'R');

    s[end]='\0';
}
```

Comment: Nice catch haha I looked at that same code for a while and for some reason didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some SegFault issues occasionaly ? I think that you should try malloc'ing two new strings with the x1 + y1 + z1 as size of the first one and x2 + y2 + z2 as the size of the second one before filling.

```
char *str1 = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (x1 + y1 + z1 + 1)); // +1 for the '\0'
// here goes the code to fill str1
printf("str1:%s\n", str1);
free(str1);
```

Don't forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: I use to get segmentation fault but that was due to my for loops not getting the right indices but I think I fixed that. but I do not think I need to malloc space for the strings because prior to calling fcfsa the maximum string length for both strings is already all of the 6 arguments added together as the max size.

Answer (score 0):

```
void change(char* s,int position,char nChar);
void fcfsa(char *s1, char *s2,int x1,int y1,int z1,int x2,int y2,int z2){
    int i,position=0;
    //*s1=(char*)calloc(x1+y1+z1+1,sizeof(char));
    //*s2=(char*)calloc(x1+x2+y2+z2+1,sizeof(char));

    //initialization of s1
    for(i=0;i<x1;i++){
          s1[position]='R';
          position++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<y1;i++){
          s1[position]='w';
          position++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<z1;i++){
          s1[position]='R';
          position++;
    }
    s1[position]='\0';


    //initialization of s2
    position=0;
    for(i=0;i<x1;i++){
          s2[position]='r';
          position++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<x2;i++){
          s2[position]='R';
          position++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<y2;i++){
          s2[position]='w';
          position++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<z2;i++)
    {
          s2[position]='R';
          position++;
    }
    s2[position]='\0';

    //printf("\ns1=%s",s1);
    //printf("\ns2=%s",s2);

    i=0;
    while(s1[i]!='\0' && s2[i]!='\0')
    {
            if(s1[i]=='R' && s2[i]=='R')
            {
                    if(s2[i]==s2[i-1])
                    {
                         change(s1,i,'r');

                    }
                    else
                    {
                     change(s2,i,'r');
                    }
            }
            i++;
    }
```

}

```
void change(char* s,int position,char nChar){

int i,length;
//char *ptr;
length=strlen(s);
//ptr=(char*)calloc(length+2,sizeof(char));
//strcpy(ptr,s);

for(i=length;i>=position;i--)
{
         s[i+1]=s[i];
}
s[position]=nChar;
```

}

Comment: Please do not just post walls of code without telling us what we're seeing.